# How to see app crashes on XCode Organizer?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an application that is uploaded trough a build machine to iTunes Connect. I'd like to be able to see the crash reports from apple service on my local machine trough `Crashes` tab on `Organizer`.

I have access to iTunes Connect and to development program for the project, I filled my credentials on XCode preferences but the app is not showing on Organizer.

At first I thought only the machine uploading the binary would be able to see this but another developer working on the project is seeing the app on his local Organizer tool

We compared settings and both seems to be the same. What Am I missing?

Answer (score 9):

Lets assert that you have followed the full following steps in order

**Step 1**: Go to Xcode -> **Preferences** ( Shortcut - ⌘ + , )

- Go to 2nd tab - **Accounts**
- Add Account selecting "**+**" from bottom left

[image: Add account]

**Step 2**: Select the team profile and download all profiles
 [image: Download team profile]

**Step 3**: Go to Windows - Organizer
[image: Windows Organizer]

**Step 4**: Select the app from left panel and let it download the crashes from server
[image: Select build and wait for crashes to download]

**Step 5**: Final and most important step select the correct build
[image: Select Build]

Do let me which is the step you are not able to reproduce on your machine. 
If everything is followed as above you should be able to see the crash logs on your xcode.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't see the app on Organizer, step 4.

Comment: @StackOverflower: i would suggest you to remove the developer account and this time do not add the account, but rather import the developer profile from your friends machine, via export developer option.

Comment: Will it take some time to reflect on Xcode organizer?
Because I see crash number in iTunes-> TestFlight. But, In organizer I get message as No crash Logs.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to isolate the problem first. Is it your computer problem, account problem or Xcode problem?

Some general techniques are:

### 1

Quit and restart Xcode

### 2

Restart you computer

### 3

Update your Xcode

### 4

1. Logout all accounts of your team in your colleague's computer
2. Quit and restart Xcode
3. Login with your account to check the Crash tab

### 5

Do the previous section of steps but with your colleague's account in your computer

### 6

Check the Console app and filter with "Xcode" for errors